# How to fix "unused argument" error message in R studio?

Tags: r, import

I tried to run my code like I usually do, and I got an "unused argument" error message. I have previously run the code multiple times and everything worked perfectly fine, this is the first time I have gotten an error message (I haven't changed the code). The only thing I've done different is I cleared the workspace at the end of my previous session (though I have no idea if this would actually affect it?).

Below is the code:

```
pacman::p_load(
  rio,        # importing data  
  here,       # relative file pathways  
  janitor,    # data cleaning and tables
  lubridate,  # working with dates
  epikit,     # age_categories() function
  tidyverse,  # data management and visualization
  skimr,
  psych,
  reshape2,   #for reshaping dataset
  dplyr,
  miscFuncs,
  foreign,    #read data formats
  rcompanion, # group means
  eeptools,
  plyr)


mesh_dat <- import(here("R", "BTmeshdata.xlsx"))
```

The error message:

```
Error in here("R", "BTmeshdata.xlsx") : 
  unused argument ("BTmeshdata.xlsx")
```

The issue seems to be in how the dataset is imported because I have the same issue with importing a dataset from a different project.

.here and my folder "R" are located in my Documents folder.

Thanks!

Comment: interesting, The `here()` package works best in conjunction with a .RProj file, are you using that as well? What happens if you try it with `import(here("./R/BTmeshdata.xlsx"))`?

Comment: You could try loading the file manually, to make sure that there's no problem with it or `rio`'s interpretation? e.g. `import(file.choose())` and point to "BTmeshdata.xlsx".

Comment: You are probably missing the slash `/`, read the documentation `?here::here()`.

Comment: @colebrookson When I use `import(here("./R/BTmeshdata.xlsx"))` I get 
`Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'`

Comment: @TechCommodities when I load the file manually there's no issue, I think the problem lies with here

Comment: @sarah.bourdin interesting. I'm not familiar with `import()`, but I would suspect the problem is with how you're using that. It's hard to know without a reprex, but if you're using the `here` package with a `.RProj` file, and it's pointing to the correct location, then there's no reason that should work unless a) there's a problem with the .xlsx file, or with the call of `import()`. Have you tried it with the tidyverse `readxl`? https://readxl.tidyverse.org/. Give it a try and see if you can successfully read in with that command. That way you know if it's the `import()` or not.